# How to get the unread message count using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

Using below query I am getting the count of all messages of a user. Now i need to filter them to unread messages only.

```
global $user;
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$count = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'message') 
 ->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid)
 ->count()
 ->execute();
```

Comment: Then you will need another `condition`.  What have you tried?  What research have you done?

Comment: I know, I need that condition only. Search results show me related to privatemessage moudule only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the privatemsg module you can use [privatemsg_unread_count()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/privatemsg/tree/privatemsg.module#n831).

Comment: I am not using privatemessage moudule.....

Comment: As Darvanen said above you need to add a condition to your query. Which field and which value to filter on depends on your model. Do you have a list of fields for the 'message' entity type? Which module implements that entity?